# Dynamic SQL in MyBatis (using foreach)

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to iterate through the list, but I am getting exception

```
org.apache.ibatis.mapping.SqlMapperException: The expression 'list' evaluated to a null value.
```

My java code:

```
public  List<SearchVO> getSearchResultByParams(List<String> selectedGroups) {
    Map map = new HashMap(1);
    map.put("selectedGroups", selectedGroups);
    return MyMapper.getSearchResultByParams(map);
}
```

MyMapper.xml:

```
<select id="getSearchResultByParams" parameterType="map" resultMap="SearchResultMap">
    SELECT *
    FROM WORK
    WHERE ID IN 
         <foreach item="selectedGroups" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{selectedGroups}
        </foreach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make sure you had set alias **map** for java.util.HashMap in mybatis-config file **typeAliases** tag

```
<select id="getSearchResultByParams" parameterType="map" resultMap="SearchResultMap">
    SELECT *
    FROM WORK
    WHERE ID IN 
         <foreach collection="selectedGroups" item="item" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{item}
        </foreach>
</select>
```

collection must be the key for you list in your map

the doc may help you http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar error resolved for me after I added

```
public SearchResultMap getSearchResultByParams(@Param("selectedGroups") List<String> selectedGroups)
```

I mean with the **`@Param`** annotation